# Is there general formula for initial guess of Newton-Raphson method for finding roots

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, newton-raphson

A few days ago, we had quiz and I solved 3/4 of questions, and I realized that the 4th question which was mentioned as wrong. Question was

> **`FIND THE SMALLEST POSITIVE ROOT BY USING NEWTON-RAPHSON METHOD`**,

I asked what's wrong with my solution, so I had an argument with my calculus teacher, about Newton's method of finding roots, specifically  about the initial guess

Example was this: $$\bf f(x)=\cos(3x) + x^3 -2$$
a root lies between 1 and 2

I said professor, that we can choose any points between them as initial guess $\bf x_0$ and had chosen **1.5**, so solved.

But, professor said, that we can pick initial guess as following formula:

- **`if f(a)f''(x) > 0 then x0 = a`** or
- **`if f(b)f''(x) > 0 then x0 = b`**,

I don't really know where she got these conditions, but I didn't reply he mail after this.

I searched google about 2 hours and **I DIDN'T FIND** any result like that. So, I wanted to ask you, who is right here? Me or her? Are we free to choose initial guess as we want, or we have to follow her instructions where it doesn't exist in real life? Or, I wrong, because even in wikipedia, there is no any info's about initial guess.

Comment: This is Darboux theorem  http://www.numdam.org/article/NAM_1869_2_8__17_0.pdf

Comment: Looking at the graph, $1.5$ is a decent guess, and it also falls under this criterion for a "good guess" that your teacher, the above comment and the below answer all give. So while it may not be the initial guess they were after, I personally really wouldn't want to call it _wrong_.

Comment: do you mean `good guess tha*n* your teacher`?

Comment: @MerdanKurbanow No, I mean "that". Syntactically simplified, the phrase says "the criterion that all those people give".

Comment: so, fact is, the criteria was not given. Teacher said that I needed to enter online classes to knew that.

Answer (score 1):

There is some very common exercise about the Newton method that guarantees convergence in the scalar case.

*Consider as base case the one where the function has a sign change and is convex and increasing on the interval $[a,b]$.*

Then the tangent $t_a(x)$ at $a$ (function value negative) could be almost horizontal, it could have a root almost anywhere, also outside of the interval. As an example consider $f(x)=x^2+0.1x-0.5$ on the interval $[a,b]=[0,1]$. The tangent in $a=0$ is $t_a(x)=0.1x-0.5$ and has its root $x=5$ well outside the interval. The tangent at $b=1$ is $t_b(x)=2.1(x-1)+0.6$ with its root at $x=\frac57$ inside the interval.

However, the tangent $t_b(x)$ at $b$ (function value positive) is more restricted in its slope and $x$-intercept. It is a supporting line of the convex curve, as is every tangent, thus always below it. Which means that at $a$ the tangent must have a negative value, $t_b(a)\le f(a)<0$, and thus its root $c$ is between $a$ and $b$, inside the interval.

The function value $0=t_b(c)\le f(c)$ at the root of the tangent has to be positive (or $c$ is already the root of $f$), so $b$ can be replaced with this root. The reduced interval $[a,b']=[a,c]$ now satisfies the same conditions. Repeating this observation gives a falling sequence of Newton iterates inside the interval converging to the root.

---

The other sign combinations of the first and second derivative (concave curve, falling curve) can now be obtained by reflections on the $x$ and $y$ axis, leading to the condition your teacher gave.

Comment: I searched for Darboux theorem on wikipedia, and it doesn't have any conditions for initial guess

Comment: @MerdanKurbanow If these conditions and not satisfied you cannot, in general, guarantee convergence... in fact, you can construct examples for which Newton's method will fail. However, if $|f(a)|/|f'(a)| < b-a $ and $|f(b)|/|f'(b)| < b - a$ the convergence is guaranteed for any $x_0 \in [a,b]$.

Comment: sir, I think you didn't understand my question.

Comment: The equation is convergent, and the root lies between x=1 and x=2, (a, b), I was talking about the initial guess (x0), from which point we can start between 1 and 2. I said professor that we can start doesn't matter from which point and I chosen x0 = 1.5, but she started from 2, because f(b)''f(b) > 0, then x0 = b. The fact is, this hint was not given in the question, so I started with 1.5, and answer I got on 2nd iteration was different than x0=2 starting point. So, im saying that, doesn't matter which you choose as guess point, and from that depends other iteration answers.

Comment: Yes indeed, in this example the iteration will stay inside the interval for any initial value. However you can construct easily examples where you go outside the interval from the wrong initial point, like $f(x)=x^2+0.1x-0.5$ for $[a,b]=[0,1]$.